# PHP validation form not returning correct response

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, undefined-index

I'm new to PHP and trying to write a bit of code that validates a form on the same page before then submitting the post to a database.

What i want is for the code to;

1. ask if any of the fields have been filled
2. if so check if any of the fields are empty (is so output a message)
3. if not go through a series of validation checks of the data each time adding any errors to an array.
4. finally ask if any errors have been found
5. if not insert the data into a database (this bit of code is written but not shown in the code i provide below.

So here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


if(isset($_POST['title']) || isset($_POST['content']) || isset($_POST['comment_option']));

{


$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$comment_option = $_POST['comment_option']; 
$form_errors = array();

if (empty($title) || empty($content) || empty($comment_option)) 
{

    $form_errors[] = "All fields are required!";

} else {

    if (strlen($title < 3)){

        $form_errors[] = "The title is too short!";

    }

    if (strlen($title > 50)){

        $form_errors[] = "The title is too long!";

    }

    if (strlen($content < 50)){

        $form_errors[] = "Post is a bit short!";

    }
}


if(!empty($form_errors)) {

print_r($form_errors);


}else{

//insert data into database

}

}
?>

<form action="add_post.php" method="post">

Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>

Content: <input type="text" name="content"><br>

Comments enabled?<br>

<input type="radio" name="comment_option" value="true">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="comment_option" value="false">No<br>

<input type="submit">


</form>




<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When i load the page i get three errors of an undefined index on the lines where i set the $title $content and $comment_option variables. If i just hit submit then i only get an error on the line where im setting the $comment_option variable but i do see "All fields are required". I also see this error if any of the fields are not filled in so this part works.

If all fields are filled in. No matter what the length i always see "Title is too short" and "Blog post is a bit short" even when they're not..

Iv spent a while looking at this and just cant figure it out what iv done wrong!

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2):

You've put the `< 3` comparison inside the function call to `strlen` (and the other two as well).  So change from

```
if (strlen($title < 3)){
```

to

```
if (strlen($title) < 3){
```

and similarly for the other comparisons.

The undefined index errors can be fixed by changing the setting of the variables to something like this:

```
$title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
```

Comment: Ah ok thats sorted the validation bit and thats working, thanks! Problem is that i still get the undefined index errors. Is is because im setting a variable with nothing in it if $_POST['?'] has nothing in it?

Comment: that is because you are checking if any variable is set, then assuming they all are.  So if `$_POST['title']` is set and `$_POST['content']` is not, you will get an undefined index when you try to set `$content = $_POST['content']`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing strlen conditional wrong.

You are doing this:

```
if (strlen($title < 3))
```

When you should be doing this:

```
if (strlen($title) < 3)
```

The reason your conditionals are failing is because you are getting the result of `strlen($title < 3)`, which results in `strlen(true)`, which results in an answer of `1` (I believe), and thus the conditional being viewed as `true`.

In the corrected case here is how the conditional works:

We are using the `strlen` function to calculate the length of `$title`, which we can say is "Test". So doing `strlen($title)` will yield `4`. Now the conditional becomes `4 < 3`, which results in `false`.

Comment: Oh right i see. Bit of a nooby error x). Thank you for telling me this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon at the end of your first IF statement:

`|| isset($_POST['comment_option']));`

That means that if the statement is true, do nothing.  Then it *always* executes the block below it.

Comment: Ok thanks that got rid of the undefined index errors at the start but i still get an error with the comment_option if i dont press something  on the radio button. I guess its because radio is true/false?

Comment: Radio buttons are either `"checked"` or `""`.  If you need to make sure that at least one in checked, then modify the HTML to default one of the radio buttons to `checked`.

Comment: In your case, you have two radio buttons with the same name.  Not a good idea.  I would change one of the names to `yes_btn` and the other to `no_btn`, then check which of `$_POST['yes_btn']` or `$_POST['no_btn']` is set to `"checked"`.

Comment: Ahhh i see. Iv set one to be checked by default and that fixes the problem. Its all sorted now :). Thanks for everyone input!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to submit the form and do these validations on the server end (PHP end) if this doesn't require the server infrastructure. You could still do these validations using JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, but what if the user turns off javascript or tries to submit the form using curl or something? You still need server-side validation.

Comment: I dont know any javascript and wouldnt know how to go about it any other way :/

Answer (score 0):

First, name your `form`:

`<form action="add_post.php" method="post" name="myForm">`

Then base your first `if` statement off the name of the `form` and remove the ';' at the end of that line:

`if(isset($_POST['myForm'])){ . . . }`

Inside that if, check and set each `$_POST` variable as you are:

```
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['comment_option']))
{
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $content = $_POST['content'];
 $comment_option = $_POST['comment_option'];
}
else
{
 $form_errors[] = "All fields are required!";
}
```

etc. for the other variables.

Do the length validation as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: using this how would output a message when not all of the fields hold data? Thanks for this advice.

Comment: Updated with checks for all variables not being empty.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem is that you have " ; " at the end of the end of the if statement.
    `if(isset($_POST['title']) || isset($_POST['content']) ||

     isset($_POST['comment_option']));`

remove it !

the other problems are in the conditions: `if (strlen($title < 3)){`
This should be `if(strlen($title) < 3){`
and so on....

The strlen return an Integer and only then you can check the condition.
What you wrote in this code is: `if(1)` or any other number....  Which is always true !

hope it helps....